# Unit Test Library (Windows Store Apps) - command line run - No test discoverer is registered to perform discovery of test cases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-store-apps, appx

I created a C# sample unit test library (windows store apps) project.
Using command line, I tried to build the solution and created .appx file using command line statements. I am able to sign it successfully. However when I run the .appx file using vstest.console.exe, I am getting "Warning: No test discoverer is registered to perform discovery of test cases. Register a test discoverer and try again"

My sample code is available at https://github.com/budgetpreneur/SampleCode/tree/master/demoutest

To reproduce the problem, just get the code into your local machine and run testrun.bat file. This batch file builds the solution, copies the required files to "demoappx" folder for appx file, runs makeappx.exe, creates cert related files and signs the .appx file before running vstest.console.exe.
The goal of this batch file is to run Windows 8 Store Apps Unit Tests automatically without user interaction.

I used Visual Studio 2012 edition for this.

Can anyone point me where I can find more information to resolve it?
Any solution or idea to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.